# Updating an Add-in removed associated lists data

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, deployment

An add-in  named 'Forms Builder' is deployed to app catalog 'Apps for SharePoint'. After modifications to the add-in code, I clicked on 'Deploy' via visual studio and cancelled it realizing the site URL was set to PROD Site URL. But , this step made the app disappear from the site contents, though, it was available in App catalog. So, I downloaded the same version and uploaded it again but it still wouldn't be seen in the site contents. Therefore, Added the app explicitly via 'Add an App'  but the lists that were associated with this app were deleted and now they are empty.

I am helpless and can't figure out why the app was deleted from the site contents. Is there a way we could get back the previous app? or any solution to come out of this situation?  Can someone please help me with this situation. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Regards

SLS

Answer (score 0):

Installing a SharePoint-hosted Add-in creates a child site of the current site. All the resources that implement the Add-in (i.e. pages, scripts, images, css) are deployed to this child site. In this scenario we refer to the site where you installed the Add-in as the **Host Web** and we refer to the child site that contains the Add-in resources as the **App Web**.

When you deploy an Add-in from Visual Studio it will check to see if the App Web already exists. If it does then Visual Studio will refresh the resources, if it doesn't Visual Studio will create the App Web and provision the resources into it.

However there are certain cases where Visual Studio needs to remove the existing App Web and replace it with a newly created one. We call this a retract and re-deploy. Changing the App Manifest is one example that requires a retract and re-deploy.

It appears that when you deployed from Visual Studio it did a retract which deleted the existing App Web and you cancelled before the new App Web could be created.

If you delete an Add-in using the SharePoint user interface it goes into the recycle bin (I know this is true for SharePoint Online. I think it's also true for the on-premises versions of SharePoint). However the last time I checked an Add-in deleted during a Visual Studio deploy does not go to the recycle bin. You can check your recycle bin to be sure.

If the Add-in isn't in the recycle bin then you'll have to go to a backup to get it back.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response Rob.Yes, I cancelled it before it could even re-deploy the app web. Hadn't I cancelled it, would the associated lists have all the data even though the app was re-installed? I am really not sure how and where to check for a backup copy in SharePoint Online. Please let me know. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Another update: There are no backups configured in our environment. Is there a way we can retrieve the list data?

Comment: 1) No. Deleting the App Web means the SharePoint site that contains the resources for the Add-in is deleted. If there were lists in the site then they get deleted along with everything else.

Comment: Oops! Do you think Microsoft will be able to restore the site collection or the site to how it was previously?

Comment: If you haven't checked the Recycle Bin I suggest you do that first. If the Add-in is not there then Microsoft should be able to restore it for you from the backups they take of your SharePoint Online sites. I believe you need to submit a support ticket for that.

Comment: I checked and the add-in is not present in the recycle bin. I'll submit a support ticket. Another quick question- Since we re-deployed the add-in, the permissions were lost and we added them via 'Apps for SharePoint' catalog. I belong to the owners group with full control but, it would still throw the 'Access Denied. You do not have permissions to view this page' error while trying to view the dashboard of the add-in after logging in with my windows credentials. While deploying, where should the permissions be set? Thank you again for all your time and help.

Comment: Clarification: The add-in was present in the 'Apps for SharePoint' catalog and hence we re-deployed it again. I meant to ask if Microsoft can retrieve the previous version of the add-in present in the 'Site Contents' along with its resources (lists)?